# Equation for weighted mean of percentages

Tags: normalization, weighted-mean, weighted-data, arithmetic

I am trying to get the equation for a weighted average of percentages to be normalized between 0 and 1. Am I doing it correctly? Thank you so much!

[image]

[image]